# Get todays records from SQL database when stored in UTC time

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have user created records that I am storing the create date in UTC in a sql database.

I want to allow the user to select a date on the UI that will pull the records for that day.

My local time is -4:00 from the UTC time. So here is my issue:

If a user created a record at 9:00AM local time (1:00PM UTC), and then another record at 10:00PM local time (2:00AM UTC the next day), how do I query both those records out when they select that day?

The records are stored in UTC so they fall in 2 separate days, but they are actually in the same day for the local time.

How would I solve this? Should I even be storing the records in UTC?

Thanks

Comment: How do you know if the customer is in your timezone? Do you have to deal with daylight savings? Also please mark the version of the SQL Server you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Is the -4 hours difference always there, or do you have multiple users from different time zones? If first one applies, consider dateadd. For example:

```
SELECT dateadd(hour, -4, yourTimeStamp) as TimeStamp
, CAST(dateadd(hour, -4, yourTimeStamp) as DATE) as DateOfTimeStamp
FROM YourTable
WHERE CAST(dateadd(hour, -4, yourTimeStamp) as DATE) = '20160510'
```

EDIT:
You can use:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, SYSDATETIME(), GETDATE()) AS MinutesOffsetUTCtoLocal
```

to get the time difference in minutes between the client and the machine. Integrating this would look like this:

```
SELECT dateadd(minute, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, SYSDATETIME(), GETDATE()), yourTimeStamp) as TimeStamp
, CAST(dateadd(minute, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, SYSDATETIME(), GETDATE()), yourTimeStamp) as DATE) as DateOfTimeStamp
FROM YourTable
WHERE CAST(dateadd(minute, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, SYSDATETIME(), GETDATE()), yourTimeStamp) as DATE) = '20160510'
```

Comment: If OP doesn't actually save the timezone but only UTC then it doesn't really matter if it is always -4, this is the only solution.

Comment: Keep in mind that daylight savings need to be accounted for. So, while EST is -5 GMT, EDT (like right now) is actually -4 GMT.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to build a calendar table with the following columns (will be handy for other things too) - in my examples it is called: `local_calendar`

```
local_date      DATE     -- This marks the day (without time)
date_starts_utc DATETIME -- Local midnight converted to UTC
date_ends_utc   DATETIME -- Local midnight of the next day converted to UTC.
```

Fill this table from and to a reasonable date range.

From now, you can join this table to any UTC time to get the local date and any local dates to utc time boundaries.

**To get the local date for a utc time**

```
SELECT local_date
FROM local_calendar
WHERE @utcTime >= date_starts_utc AND @utcTime < date_ends_utc
```

**To get the UTC boundaries for a local date**

```
SELECT @lowerBoundary = date_starts_utc, @higherBoundary = date_ends_utc
FROM local_calendar
WHERE date = @localDate
```